# How to control Javascript's async/await behaviour in case of an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I was trying ES6 Async/Await feature and it's easier to implement using async/await rather than Genrators and Promise.

For instance when we are calling a promise function(`getActiveSession` in the below snippet) from `async` function - if Promise fails it will be caught in the `catch` block and is handled.

```
 async function createSession(context) {
  try {
    let activeSession = await getActiveSession(context);
    if (activeSession) {
      return activeSession;
    } else {
      let session = await createNewSession(context);
      return session;
    }
  } catch (createSessionException) {
    throw createSessionException;
  }
}
```

What if I need to continue without breaking the program flow? i.e I need to create a `newSession` if `getActiveSession` fails.

Currently, if `getActiveSession` promise is rejected with error `No Session Found` - same error message is thrown to `createSession` as well.

Comment: well, i mean, you'd do something other than re-throwing the error.

Comment: what kevin said..........................................

Comment: @apsillers - updated question

Comment: what you want is if activeSession is rejected, you still want to be able to handle it and try for createNewSession right ?

Answer (score 0):

> What if I need to continue without breaking the program flow? i.e I need to create a newSession if getActiveSession fails.

Then create a new session if `getActiveSession` fails (or returns `null`):

```
async function createSession(context) {
  try {
    let activeSession = await getActiveSession(context);
    if (activeSession) {
      return activeSession;
    }
  } catch (ex) { }
  return await createNewSession(context);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, `try...catch` in js needs to be written with `catch (err)`

Comment: @UlysseBN Fixed. BTW your answer has the same problem.

Comment: Nice catch, fixed it also!

Answer (score -1):

Add the logic you want in your `catch` block instead of throwing an error.

The error you rethrow in catch block is in fact the reason why your `async` function reject instead of resolving.

```
async function foo() {
    try {
        throw new Error("let's go to the catch block")
    } catch (e) {
        return safelyCreateSession()
    }
}
```

if you still want to rethrow from the function, this means you'll want to handle this in the function that calls it:

```
async function main() {
    let result;
    try {
        result = await aFunctionThatThrows()
    } catch (e) {
        result = aFunctionThatDoesNotThrow()
    }
    // use result
}
```

Comment: I didn't feel `Add the logic you want in your catch block instead of throwing an error.` alone was a useful answer.

Comment: @KevinB well according to the question there is not any more accurate answer... I still felt I could add an example though to ensure it is understandable.

Comment: i mean, it's better now that you added code, but, that should have been there from the start.

Comment: @KevinB So I still deserve a downvote because of something I fixed, that's a little bit weird, and really doesn't really encourage answers improvement

Comment: yeah, I have tried this. But one of my colleague advised me not to handle this logic in the catch block.

Is it fine doing things in the catch block?

Comment: _is it fine?_ well It really depend on the context. But IMO you should somewhere handle this logic instead of throwing to the user. I edited my answer to show you another place you could handle the error